# Why google chrome won't read .txt files

Tags: html, google-chrome

Why won't google chrome read `.txt files` and it only reads `.html files`? I mean the browser would read the declaration for `html5` and would realise that he must transform that into a `webpage` right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why won't google chrome read .txt files and it only reads .html files?

It does.

If I go to `File > Open` in my copy of Chrome and then select a text file, it opens it in the viewport.

> I mean the browser would read the declaration for html5 and would realise that he must transform that into a webpage right?

No.

Browsers use the Content-Type (inferred from the file extension for local files) to determine how to handle the file. They don't generally perform content sniffing.